# react native google-signin failed in android(Developer error)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-signin

I am trying to use "react native google-signin" It was failed in android. I am using firebase.
It can be clicked (google-signin button) and then can put ID text in but after finishing login process, It doesn't pass to next page.

I got 'developer error' message.

```
    WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR
promiseMethodWrapper@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2831:45http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:123365:45
generatorResume@[native code]
asyncGeneratorStep@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:28377:26
_next@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:28396:29
tryCallOne@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:33548:16http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:33629:27http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:35012:26
_callTimer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:34891:17
_callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:34936:17
callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:35142:44
__callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3286:46http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3060:45
__guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3259:15
flushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lovedog&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3059:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

I tried some ways to solve the problem.

```
1. client id : I used type 3 - in oauth client.

2. I generated new keytool and used SHA-1, SHA-256 from it and then reuploaded google-service.json file.
```

and then I don't know well what I need to try.
could you give me some advices, plz?

/android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15' 
    }
}
```

I wrote code like this.

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Header} from '../components/Header/Header';
import {useRootNavigation} from '../navigation/RootStackNavigation';
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  GoogleSigninButton,
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const IntroScreen: React.FC = () => {
  const rootNavigation = useRootNavigation<'Intro'>();
  const safeArea = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const onPressGoogleSignin = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const isSignIn = await GoogleSignin.isSignedIn();
      if (isSignIn) {
        await GoogleSignin.signOut();
      }

      const result = await GoogleSignin.signIn({});
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        result.idToken,
      );
      const authResult = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);

      rootNavigation.push('Signup', {
        screen: 'InputEmail',
        params: {
          preInput: {
            email: result.user.email,
            name: result.user.name ?? 'Unknown',
            profileImage: result.user.photo ?? '',
          },
          uid: authResult.user.uid,
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // 여기서 예외를 처리하십시오.
      console.error('Google Signin Error:', error);
      // 예외 처리 로직을 추가하세요.
    }
  }, [rootNavigation]);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Header>
        <Header.Title title="IntroScreen" />
      </Header>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          paddingBottom: 32 + safeArea.bottom,
        }}>
        <GoogleSigninButton onPress={onPressGoogleSignin} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had Two issues First one is Above and Second was `An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project.` Second issues was in Firebase while adding SHA1 in project. I ressolved this issue

1. Delete debug.keystore
2. Then regenerated it by this `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 10000`
3. Then Got SHA1 and SHA256 by this command `keytool -keystore debug.keystore -list -v` after giving password that is located in
   `android/App/build.gradle then signingConfigs there is store password`
4. Added SHA1 and SHA256 in Firebase my project
5. Download the latest JSON file add that latest JSON in my project `android/App` folder
6. then clean gradle by `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
7. Uninstall App then do `npx react-native run-android`
8. Now its working :)

I used this link [How to Implement Google Login in React Native with Firebase](https://www.pradipdebnath.com/2020/10/06/how-to-implement-google-login-in-react-native-with-firebase/) also a [Youtube video Youtube Video Related Previous Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdYp5JdMvs0&list=PLQWFhX-gwJbmrCwksjn77tdl36dIWPFAt&index=5&ab_channel=PradipDebnath)